# Percentile calculation based on a known percentile table

Tags: r

I have two data about people's weights. One is from normal patients, and another is about patients with a specific disease.

Let's say:

```
weight_Normals <- c(170, 140, 122, 143, 156, 122, 189, 200, 201, 133, 155, .....)
weight_Disease <- c(220, 145, 167, 177, 190, 130, 169, 100, 230, 210, 222, .....)
```

I can compute the percentile from 0.01 to 0.99 of weight_Normals. However, how should I use this percentile results from normal patient to map into the patients with diasease? In other words, I would like to calculate the percentile of these patients with disease based on the percentiles of normal patients.

Comment: qWeightNormal <- quantile(weight_Normals, probs=seq(0,1,0.01))
So, I can know the percentiles of weight_Normals. Then, how do I know the mapping of each weight of patient with disease to the percentile of noemal patient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, "what proportion of the first sample are less than or equal to a given observation in the second sample?"

```
apply(outer(weight_Normals,weight_Disease,"<="),2,sum)/length(weight_Normals)
```

Test:

```
weight_Normals <- c(170, 140, 122, 143, 156, 122, 189, 200, 201, 133, 155)
weight_Disease <- c(220, 145, 167, 177, 190, 130, 169, 100, 230, 210, 222)
apply(outer(weight_Normals,weight_Disease,"<="),2,sum)/length(weight_Normals)

 print(apply(outer(a,b,"<="),2,sum)/length(a),digits=4)
 [1] 1.0000 0.4545 0.6364 0.7273 0.8182 0.1818 0.6364 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
```

So for example, the second disease patient weighs at least as much as 45.45% of the first sample.

---

**Alternative version to handle ties symmetrically**

Consider if we had Normal patients with weights 137, 140, 151, 166 and 173, and disease patients with weights 150, 151 and 152.

The ones with weights 150 and 152 are easy enough. "150" is 2/5 of the way through the sample. It is at the 40th percentile of the other sample. Similarly, "152" is at the 60th percentile. But "151" is exactly equal to the median of the other sample. While a strict definition of cdfs would have us compute the proportion less than or equal to it (giving 0.6 or 60%), for exact equality it may make sense to estimate that as 50%. That would give the following calculation:

```
left <- apply(outer(weight_Normals,weight_Disease,"<"),2,sum)/length(weight_Normals)
right <- apply(outer(weight_Normals,weight_Disease,"<="),2,sum)/length(weight_Normals)

percent.wties <- (left+right)/2
print(percent.wties, digits=4)
```

(This gives the same answers as before on the example)

---

*Smoothing considerations?*

If your samples are small you might want to consider using smoother estimates of what the percentile ranks are than the sample proportions, either by fitting some assumed parametric form of distribution or by kernel density estimation. [This is occasionally done; if it doesn't sound like what you want, I wouldn't worry about it at all.]

Comment: Please let me make sure I understood this correctly. So, the answer I obtained here would be the percentile of each weight from patient with disease if I compare them to the normal patient? Really appreciate your time.

Comment: For a given patient with disease, this gives the percentage of normal patients with weight less than or equal to it, which is simply my understanding of what you're asking for. If you mean something else, could you make your request more precise? Said another way - if you mean something else, could you define quantile so I can figure out what you mean? Even if I did understand correctly, it could reasonably be argued that I should average "<" and "<=" results when approximating the population percentiles, though in the example data it makes no difference (there being no ties across samples).

Comment: So for example, consider the patient with weight "145". There are 5 (out of 11) "Normal" patients with lower weight. Now 5/11 is 45.45%. That's all I computed. We just need to be sure that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your explanination. The second version gave me a clear idea about this question. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You might enjoy trying out an alternative approach in `R`, Glen, using `ecdf`.  Example: `ecdf(weight_Normals)(weight_Disease)`. For larger reference datasets it should be much more efficient, too.

Comment: @whuber thanks, I really should have thought to do that.

Comment: No need to be self-deprecating: there is so much going on in `R` that almost no matter what solution you propose to a basic problem, somebody will eventually jump in and point to a built-in solution. I think the `ecdf` method is worth remembering, though, not only because it replaces a quadratic-time calculation with an $n\log(n)$-time calculation, but it also provides one of the few ways in `R` to do efficient linear searches.

Comment: It's really a very neat approach, and yes, will be much faster, especially in large samples. `ecdf` is very handy. I doubt that it would have occurred to me to use it to do searches. That's clever.